# The current path, items/2343/16/4/, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, django, python-2.x

В файле lesson_two\urls.py работают все регулярные выражения кроме последнего. При переходе на `url(r'^items/(P<year>[0-9]{4})/(P<mounth>[0-9]{2})/(P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.day_archive, name="day_archive")/` появляется ошибка "Page not found (404)". Не могу понять в чём проблема.

**courses_django\urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
# from django.contrib import admin
# from lesson_two import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'', include('lesson_one.urls')),
    # path(r'^ admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^', views.home),
    url(r'^', include('lesson_two.urls'))
]
```

**lesson_two\urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^items$', views.items, name="items"),
    url(r'^items/2003/$', views.special_case_2003, name="special_case_2003"),
    url(r'^items/([0-9]{4,5})/$', views.year_archive, name="year_archive"),
    url(r'^items/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive, name="month_archive"),
    url(r'^items/(P<year>[0-9]{4})/(P<mounth>[0-9]{2})/(P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.day_archive, name="day_archive")
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home page")


def items(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to items page")


def special_case_2003(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to items/2003/ page")


def year_archive(request, a):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to [0-9]{4} %s" % a)


def month_archive(request, year, month):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to %s year" % year)


def day_archive(request, month, year, day):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to month, %s, day" % year)
```

Comment: Я не специалист по питону, но мне кажется, что делая именованную группу в регулярном выражении, вы забыли поставить знак `?` перед `P`. То есть, пример, `P<group>` заменить нужно на `?P<group>`. И еще, вы делаете проверку строки `items/2343/16/4/`, на конце у вас стоит одна цифра - 4. А в регулярном выражении строго стоит две цифры `[0-9]{2}`, можете изменить на `[0-9]{1,2}`.

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение: https://regex101.com/r/lB59ZX/1, исправленное: https://regex101.com/r/QE0N0h/1

Comment: @Let'ssayPie спасибо вам большое. Всё сразу заработоло.

Comment: внимательнее будьте :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте во все именные группы знак вопроса после открывающей скобки:

`(P<year>[0-9]{4})` **=>** `(?P<year>[0-9]{4})`

Синтаксис именных групп в регулярных выражениях Python таков:

```
(?P<name>pattern)
(?P<имя>шаблон)
```

`P` означает *особое расширение языка Python* (*Python-specific extension*), см. [эту переписку](https://markmail.org/message/oyezhwvefvotacc3) авторов Python и Perl (*(`?P` syntax could be
permanently reserved for Python-specific syntax extensions*).

Имя группы должно быть валидным идентификатором языка Python, то есть должно быть цифро-буквенной строкой и начинаться с буквы. Буквы только латинские, русские не поддерживаются. Знак подчёркивания разрешён, но дефисы недопустимы. Длина имени группы не может превышать 32 символов.